Vuetify Grid v-col, fill-height not reaching all rows
This image shows what is going on... Box Five has extra text, and I am using fill-height on all v-cards to make matching heights for all cards..but this is only applied per row, not to all rows inside the v-row. Without hard-coding a specific height for all my cards, how can I make all cards be a uniform height?

<template>
  <div>
    <v-container class="bg-surface-variant mb-6">
      <v-row>
        <v-col md="4" class="align-center justify-center">
          <v-card class="fill-height pa-2 ma-2">
            <div style="padding-right: 10px; flex-grow: 1; text-align: left">
              Box One
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col md="4" class="align-center justify-center">
          <v-card class="fill-height pa-2 ma-2">
            <div style="padding-right: 10px; flex-grow: 1; text-align: left">
              Box Two
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col md="4" class="align-center justify-center">
          <v-card class="fill-height pa-2 ma-2">
            <div style="padding-right: 10px; flex-grow: 1; text-align: left">
              Box Three
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col md="4" class="align-center justify-center">
          <v-card class="fill-height pa-2 ma-2">
            <div style="padding-right: 10px; flex-grow: 1; text-align: left">
              Box Four
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col md="4" class="align-center justify-center">
          <v-card class="fill-height pa-2 ma-2">
            <div style="padding-right: 10px; flex-grow: 1; text-align: left">
              Box Five with extra text to show wrapping
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="align-center justify-center" md="4">
          <v-card class="fill-height pa-2 ma-2">
            <div style="padding-right: 10px; flex-grow: 1; text-align: left">
              Box Six
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>


Well, you can truncate the text to allow only a certain number of characters but if the aim is to show everything then you might have to explicitly set a height

I am trying to do this without truncating, and setting a specific height for each card..possible?

I don't think this is the best answer, but it seems like vuetify grid uses flexbox model, but in your case, I think it's better to use grid model instead, you might need to at least hardcode the minimum width though (I will use 200px). To use grid, we can use the following style for the <v-row>:
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(
  auto-fit,
  minmax(min(200px, 100%), 1fr)
);
grid-auto-rows: 1fr;

You can add that to style attribute of <v-row>.
After that, you need to remove md="4" from <v-col>.
The full code will be like this:
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container class="bg-surface-variant mb-6">
      <v-row
        style="
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(
            auto-fit,
            minmax(min(200px, 100%), 1fr)
          );
          grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
        "
      >
        <v-col class="align-center justify-center">
          <v-card class="fill-height pa-2 ma-2">
            <div style="padding-right: 10px; flex-grow: 1; text-align: left">
              Box One
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="align-center justify-center">
          <v-card class="fill-height pa-2 ma-2">
            <div style="padding-right: 10px; flex-grow: 1; text-align: left">
              Box Two
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="align-center justify-center">
          <v-card class="fill-height pa-2 ma-2">
            <div style="padding-right: 10px; flex-grow: 1; text-align: left">
              Box Three
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="align-center justify-center">
          <v-card class="fill-height pa-2 ma-2">
            <div style="padding-right: 10px; flex-grow: 1; text-align: left">
              Box Four
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="align-center justify-center">
          <v-card class="fill-height pa-2 ma-2">
            <div style="padding-right: 10px; flex-grow: 1; text-align: left">
              Box Five with extra text to show wrapping
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="align-center justify-center">
          <v-card class="fill-height pa-2 ma-2">
            <div style="padding-right: 10px; flex-grow: 1; text-align: left">
              Box Six
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

Vuetify demo
